# Lua parameters not expanding properly

Tags: parameters, lua, variable-length

I am pretty new to Lua and maybe this is a noobie question but why is the below code failing? As far as I understand foo returns two parameters and since in Lua you can pass as many parameters as your heart desires the first passes just fine but the second call fails the assert.

```
function foo()
 return true, {}
end

function bar(a,b,c)
 assert(type(b)=="table", "Expected table as the second parameter")
 print("Fine")
end

bar(foo())      -- Fine
bar(foo(),true) -- Expected table as the second parameter
```

https://www.lua.org/cgi-bin/demo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please read [Lua 3.5 Reference Manual: 3.4 Expressions](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4)

> Both function calls and vararg expressions can result in multiple
>   values. If a function call is used as a statement (see §3.3.6), then
>   its return list is adjusted to zero elements, thus discarding all
>   returned values. If an expression is used as the last (or the only)
>   element of a list of expressions, then no adjustment is made (unless
>   the expression is enclosed in parentheses). In all other contexts, Lua
>   adjusts the result list to one element, either discarding all values
>   except the first one or adding a single nil if there are no values.

`foo(),true` is a list of expressions that resolves to `true, true` as `foo()` is neither the only nor the last expression of that list.
Whereas `true, foo()` would resolve to `true, true, {}`